# unable to understand how component is passed to child element and how render method works in React.js

Tags: reactjs, mern

i am begginner to  react and know only basics of react ,i understand how props works but in this tutorial that i am following they passed the complete component as prop , here is the code

child element code :

```
import { Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom";

    const Privateroute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
      console.log("this is the passed component", Component);
    
      return (
        <div>
          <Route {...rest}  render={(props) => localStorage.getItem("authToken") ? (
                <Component {...props} />
              ) : (
                <Redirect to="/" />
              )
            }
          />
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default Privateroute;
```

i dont understand what does the **component:Component** mean in component parameters  and where does the ...rest came from  and lastly what does  the **<Route {..rest}  >** mean , kidnly can some explins these in some basic steps

here is the parent code

```
  <Route exact path="/signup"   component={Register}    />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax `{component: Component, ...rest}` is called destructuring assignment, it means that the props passed should contain a property called `component`, which is of type `Component`, and rest will be an object containing all other properties passed in the props object by the parent component.

As you can see, `rest` is spread on th `Route` component, meaning that all other properties (beside the `component` property) will be passed as props to the `Route` component.

See : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: thanks alot  for your help , i have  still some confusion in your last commnet you talk about rest having all other properties except the componet, as you can see in the parent element code there arent any other properties passed .   <Route exact path="/signup"   component={Register}    />, just one component which i understand we get from the component:Component so , where does the {...rest} values/properties come from .?

Comment: So it means that rest will be equal to {exact: true, path: '/signup'} : all props passed except the one named 'component'. But I see that the child component is called Privateroute and not Route, is there a confusion here ?

Comment: thanks , the PrivateRoute  is component created to check weather there is data with key "authToken" and if it returns true it renders the component we get from parameters else it redirects  back to login page

Comment: atleast thats wht i think of it :)

Answer (score 1):

Assigning to new variable names
A property can be unpacked from an object and assigned to a variable with a different name than the object property.

Reference where I took these examples and explanations - I would suggest reading this carefully before continuing to learn javascript or react.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

**component: Component explanation**

```
const o = {p: 42, q: true};
const {p: foo, q: bar} = o;

console.log(foo); // 42
console.log(bar); // true
```

**...rest - Explanation**

Rest in Object Destructuring
The Rest/Spread Properties for ECMAScript proposal (stage 4) adds the rest syntax to destructuring. Rest properties collect the remaining own enumerable property keys that are not already picked off by the destructuring pattern.

```
let {a, b, ...rest} = {a: 10, b: 20, c: 30, d: 40}
a; // 10
b; // 20
rest; // { c: 30, d: 40 }
```

**<Route {..rest} >**

This means your passing all the properties inside of rest object to the Route component.

```
<Route {..rest} >
```

The route component is a ready to use component from react-router library - https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Router

Would suggest reading how react-router lib works or watch a tutorial to get a clear understanding

Comment: thanks alot for your help  and time  . your answer was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

`...rest` is having remaining key-values of props, this is basically ES6 feature, this is not subjected to MERN stack.
`component: Component`
this basically creates a variable named as Component which holds the value of key `component`.